# Error: MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity [Instantiatable]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried upgrading Android Gradle Plugin from 4.2.2 to 7.0.1 using the [upgrade assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#agp-upgrade-assistant) which is available in Android Studio at Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant.  The only change it made was to my project-level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1' // changed from 4.2.2 to 7.0.1
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, now when I run `./gradlew assemble assembleAndroidTest` I get the following error:

```
/builds/locuslabs/android-team/locuslabs-android-sdk/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:21: Error: MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity [Instantiatable]
            android:name="com.locuslabs.appsdk.MainActivity"
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Explanation for issues of type "Instantiatable":
   Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest
   file (or for custom views, in a layout file) must be "instantiatable" by
   the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have an
   empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a static
   inner class.
1 errors, 0 warnings
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

My project is multi-module, but I don't suspect that as the problem since it's complaining about the application module, not a library module.

I believe my `<activity>` tag is well formed in my AndroidManifest.xml for my application module:

```xml
        <activity
            android:name="com.locuslabs.appsdk.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Furthermore, I don't think there is anything wrong with extending `AppCompatActivity` instead of `android.app.Activity` as I'm doing in my MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // ...
}
```

I'm concerned that Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.1 is not really ready for prime-time because the [Android Gradle Plugin documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) still says `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'` instead of 7.0.1.

I saw that the [Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.1 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#lint-behavior-changes) mentioned some changes to linting but none of those changes seemed relevant to me.

I also skimmed through the [Android Gradle Plugin source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/) to see if I could find the linting stage any identify any changes but it looked like a lot of work to find that code and do that analysis.

I searched for answers but all I could find were these two stackoverflow entries where the error was legitimate and the programmer just needed to change their code to ensure they were referencing an actual `Activity`:

1. [Android Studio Error: Activity must extend android.app.activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66783279/android-studio-error-activity-must-extend-android-app-activity)
2. [MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379723/mainactivity-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity)

I also tried Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.0 but got the same error.  Only Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2 prevents the error.

Is this a bug in Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.1?

**Update: could not disable `Instantiatable`**

I tried to disable the `Instantiatable` lint error the following ways but none of them prevented the error.

First, I tried adding `disable "Instantiatable"` to my application-level build.gradle file:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable "Instantiatable"
    }
}
```

Second, I tried prepending `@SdkSuppress("Instantiatable")` to the class:

```kotlin
@SdkSuppress("Instantiatable")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   // ...
}
```

Similarly, I tried `@SuppressLint("Instantiatable")` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What about the "answers" mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22821420/this-class-should-be-public-android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbarview-ho) that are more about AS settings itself, and also seem like a workaround. In Artic Fox: Settings -> Editor -> Inspections

Comment: There is an opened issue for this problem.  Disabling "Instantiatable" is only a bypass.  There could be other concerns. see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196406778

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> the Android Gradle Plugin documentation still says classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0' instead of 7.0.1.

You need to read further down the page, to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#versioning-update) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#7-0-0). That table is only relevant for pre-7.0.0 versions.

> Is this a bug in Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.1?

Quite possibly. Or, perhaps beyond, as the `Instantiatable` Lint check [has a history of problems](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=Instantiatable).

If your scenario does not match one of those three August 2021 bugs, and you are in position to provide a reproducible test case, file a fresh issue! Beyond that, if a clean-and-rebuild is not clearing up your problem, you might need to simply disable the `Instantiatable` Lint check for the time being by adding the following to *all* of your build.gradle files at the application or library level (i.e. all except your project-level build.gradle):

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable "Instantiatable"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare.  I don't think those three August 2021 Android Gradle Plugin issues referenced at https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/08/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-patch.html are the issue.

Comment: when you say "file a fresh issue" are you referring to a fresh issue on stackoverflow or somewhere else (where?)

Comment: I tried two methods for disabling `Instantiatable` which I've just described as an update to my original post (see "Update: could not disable `Instantiatable`").  Do you know of any other way to disable it?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky: "are you referring to a fresh issue on stackoverflow or somewhere else (where?)" -- I was referring to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky: "I tried two methods for disabling Instantiatable" -- I am very surprised that the first one did not work. You mentioned that you have multiple modules. Have you disabled `Instantiatable` in all of them? Are you still getting the error from a command-line build, or only from within Studio? I see `Instantiatable` in Settings > Editor > Inspections, and you could change the severity there, but AFAIK that's for IDE inspections, and your error report sure seems like a Lint check, which is related but separate.

Comment: you were right!  After I added disable "Instantiatable" to *all* of my `android { lintOptions {}}` blocks then my `./gradlew assemble assembleAndroidTest` command succeeded.  I edited your answer by adding this key detail and will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: As for filing a fresh issue in [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues), the problem is similar to [AGP 4.0 false positive Instantiatable Lint check if Application extends java class](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158128960) except it applies to Android Gradle Plugin 7.0.0 and 7.0.1 not 4.0 and it applies to the Activity, not to the Application.  Considering that issue was marked resolved, I tried to reproduce on a new project but couldn't so I didn't file it.  I guess it has something to do with some config option in my project.

Comment: When I add that `lintOptions` line I get `...failed: ... .gradle/caches/jars-9/o_ad21f02729bd9fcad5f9c9e683636547/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar` without further information. Why?

Comment: In case you want to know where to add this code, search for `compileSdkVersion` and add this block blow it `lintOptions {
        disable "Instantiatable"
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can use the lint config **xml file** and add this "Instantiatable" rule as "ignored":

```xml
<lint>
    [...]
    <issue id="Instantiatable" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

In addition, you should configure lint plugin in your `build.gradle` to use the `lint.xml` file:

```
android {
[...]
    lint {
        lintConfig = file("$rootDir/config/lint.xml")
    }
}
```